# What's lazy about views on Scala's mutable collections?

Tags: scala, collections, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

I think this question is essentially about what laziness is in the context of mutability.

In *Programming in Scala* (or [the docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html)), they give examples of how to use views on immutable and mutable collections. In that section, they state

> [*transformer* methods] take at least one collection as their receiver object and produce another collection in their result. ... A *view* is a special kind of collection that represents some base collection, but implements all of its transformers lazily.

They give examples with immutable collections and I understand how laziness works there. But I'm struggling with the role laziness plays in the example with a mutable collection:

> Many transformer functions on [views over mutable sequences] provide a window into the original sequence ... an example ...

```
val arr = (0 to 9).toArray
val subarr = arr.view.slice(3, 6)
```

> The view does not copy these elements, it just provides a reference to them.

```
def negate(xs: collection.mutable.Seq[Int]) = 
  for (i <- 0 until xs.length) xs(i) = - xs(i)

negate(subarr)
arr  // Array(0, 1, 2, -3, -4, -5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

I understand why we get that answer. But what is lazy about the transformer `slice`? I had understood laziness to mean that values are only computed when needed (like with the immutable collections examples). But the values in `slice` are never computed, they are just references to those in `arr`, even after calling `negate`. Is this my misunderstanding of laziness? Or are the docs using laziness in another way? Or something else?

Comment: Every lazy thing that happens with the immutable collections happens with the mutable collections too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better example of this lazy behavior:

```
val a = Array(1,2,3)
val b = a.map(_ + 5)
val c = a.view.map(_ + 5)
println(b(1)) //prints 7
println(c(1)) // prints 7

a(1) = 5

println(b(1)) // still prints 7, since that array was computed on instantiation
println(c(1)) // now prints 10, since elements of c are lazily evaluated each time.
```